# How to define a hashtable of hashtable in Racket?

Tags: functional-programming, hashtable, racket

I want to define a hash table to represent such a data structure:

(("A" , ("B" ,16)) , ("B" , ("C" , 20)))

and I need to access to the both pairs: ("B" ,16),("C" ,20) and numbers 16,20.

Can I have a hashtable of hashtable in Racket? how should I define it and access to to elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. Yes, it is possible. One can simply do it like:

```
(define (fun1) 

 (let ([ht (make-hash (list (cons "A" (make-hash '(("B" "16")("C" "20"))))))])

    ht))

(define v (hash-ref (fun1) "A" ))

(hash-ref v "B")
```